# Cosmos client SDK FeedIterator.ReadNextAsync() not returning from await

Tags: .net-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a .NET Maui Blazor app that uses Cosmos Db for the data store. I'm experiencing an issue on queries to Cosmos with the Cosmos client SDK. (version: 3.36.0)

The issue is the same issue as described in this article (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-fix-the-feediteratorreadnextasync-response-not-returning-when). The `feedIterator.ReadNextAsync()` never returns, though I do see the query execute properly in Cosmos Db logs. It is returning the data as expected but the call never returns. Code execution just immediately falls through to the UI code which promptly errors due to not having expected data. I have tried the workaround in the article (task.Wait, task.Result) and it does seem to work, but it doesn't seem like a good idea for 2 reasons, one is that, while not an async programming guru, I understand that doing what it recommends is not a good practice. Secondly it isn't addressing the root issue, though I don't know what the root cause is and hence the inquiry.

Additionally, in my case, it seems especially strange since it is being executed from a generic method which works on some types of data but not on others. As an example, I have 2 (really more than 2 but for this example) types of data (Activity and Exercise). Both stored in the same Cosmos Collection and in this case, using the same code. When I  all the method with Activity as the type, everything works great. But with Exercise as the type, things fail as described above.

```
    internal async Task<T> GetItemFromCloudAsync<T>(string partitionKey, string id, string secondaryid = null) where T : class, new()
    {
        Container container = await GetContainer();

        string doctype = await ValidateTypeAndGetDoctype<T>();

        string key = await GetKeyByType<T>();
        string secondaryKey = await GetSecondaryKeyByType<T>();

        string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Doctype = '{doctype}' and c.UserIdentifier = '{partitionKey}' and c.{key} = '{id}'";

        if (secondaryid != null && doctype == "ActivityLog")
        {
            sqlQuery = sqlQuery + $" and {secondaryKey} = {secondaryid}";
        }

        using (FeedIterator<T> feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(new QueryDefinition(sqlQuery)))
        {
            while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                // Problematic line of code.
                FeedResponse<T> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();

                if (response.Count == 1)
                {
                    return response.FirstOrDefault<T>();
                }
                if (response.Count > 1)
                {
                    // todo: determine what to do in this case if anything. At least log the condition for now.
                }
            }
        }

        return new T();
    }
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on this. I would rather find and address the root cause than continue down the path of the workaround in the above article.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: Is this code called using `Wait` or `Result`?

Comment: If you're asking about the code that is calling this method, it is not. It (and the entire call chain) is using await...

Comment: Are you creating the CosmosClient in Gateway mode or Direct mode?

Comment: It is being created in Direct mode.